# Min Max DB Value from Model object where end value is known

Tags: laravel, eloquent, tostring, laravel-blade

I think I'm probably coming at this completely backward, so if there is an obvious method, I'd be grateful.

Using an Eloquent model, I have a value for a related model property.  In many cases, I would like to colorize the output if it is low, medium, or high against min/max in the *database* for that property.

E.g. model value is 9.  Database max is 10, min is 1.  So I would color this red based on its percentage.

Model is $prog.  Related model is drLevel.  Value is RTO.  So - my chain looks like this:  $prog->drLevel->RTO.

In blade, I can easily display the value (9).  What I'd like to do is colorize it using the simplest / thinnest code.

**This works** obviously:

```
{!! format( $prog->drLevel->RTO, $prog->drLevel->min('RTO'), $prog->drLevel->max('rto') ) !!}
```

and the method would be roughly:

```
function format($value, $min, $max){
     switch by $value vs $min/$max, color appropriately
     return the value with color
   }
```

While fine, I'm doing this 100s of times.  I was trying to find a clean way to reduce code and only send the object itself through to the method:

```
{!! format( $prog->drLevel->RTO) !!}
```

and then on the method, pick the object apart and reuse the snippet for every object passed in something like:

```
function format($value){
  $model = findTheObjectBase($value)   // Should return $prog->drLevel
  $property = findTheLastChainedElementStringValue($value)  // Should return 'RTO'
  $min = $model->min($property)
   etc.
}
```

No idea how to do the above...

I'm guessing that my depending on a change from an object name to a string so that it fits within the ->min()  function is a bad idea... but I'm trying to make this clean / reduce code without having to add a method to every single property within the model.

Fool's errand?  Or am I just missing a much easier way to do this?

Comment: You can write a method within the drLevel model, even you can overload the RTO atrribute using the [Accessors](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method with the drLevel model,

```
public function formattedRTO() {
    $value = $this->RTO;
    $max = App\drLevel::all()->max('RTO');
    $min = App\drLevel:all()->min('RTO');
    // now you have min, max and current value, form here return whatever you want, using switch maybe
    return formated_result;
}
```

Now you can simply use it like,

```
{{ $prog->drLevel->formattedRTO(); }}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you @akshendra Pratap.  I agree, this would be useful if I had just one property.  I have dozens - so this would not help allow me to pass a single model to the generic 'format' class.  I'd still have to write a specific format function for every property.  I was hoping to be able to pick apart the model chain and operate on the chain as I showed above.  I'm thinking this may not be possible and I'm just stuck passing the specific values for each different property every time into the function

Comment: You can make this general by passing, the attribute string, then using $this->getAttribute('atrribute-string') to get the current value, min and max can also be extracted easily. At least on format function for one model is possible this way.

Comment: Yes, but I'm back to the original problem - how do I extract the attribute *string* from the chain?  IE  if I have 50 attributes for $prog->drLevel->xxx  How do I extract the xxx for each one without explicitly stating it by passing a string in the method call?

Comment: Yeah, the way I am saying will have a call like $prog->drLevel->formattedAttr('xxx'), instead of $prog->drLevel->xxx. Don't know if extracting the attribute name is possible or not. You might find some help in Laravel source code.